# Angular http json request issue

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-http

Hello I have a simple question but I'm running into problems. I edited some code that I found on line. I'm trying to utilize an Angular http service to retrieve JSON data but it doesn't seem to be working

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $http.get('https://www.dropbox.com/s/325d678ksplb7qs/names.json')
    sucess(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.posts = data;
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // log error
  });

});
```

My code example is below

**http://codepen.io/jimmyt1001/pen/dPVveN**

Comment: "sucess", should be "success" also you need another dot before success

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is because you are using Dropbox as the data source. Even though it looks like it should return a json file, the URL you used actually return a dropbox web page with the json file rendered.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

It should be like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http)
{
    $http.get('https://www.dropbox.com/s/325d678ksplb7qs/names.json')
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config)
        {
            $scope.posts = data;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config)
        {
            // log error
        });
});
```

I.e. you're missing a dot (`.`) before `success` and your `success` is incorrectly typed (you type `sucess`).

**Original**

Your code should be structured like this:

```
// Simple GET request example :
$http.get('/someUrl').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

As explained in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Yours is like this:

```
$http.get('https://www.dropbox.com/s/325d678ksplb7qs/names.json')
   sucess(function(data, status, headers, config) {
```

Wherea you're missing a dot (.) before the success, and your success is spelled wrong (yours is sucess).

It's decent practice to copy existing demos until you're certain on how they're really setup. Also, use your developer tools to catch easy bugs like this.

It's also possible that your dropbox call is simply invalid, but if you fix your code accordingly then the error method should be able to catch it and you should be able to see the error.

Comment: Great answers! Thank you all! That fixed the problem but I still can't see data believe Vinh Tran was right on this one. My data not displaying may also have something to do with me using placing my JSON file in dropbox

Answer (score 1):

You spelled wrong `sucess` should be `success`

**CODE**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $http.get('https://www.dropbox.com/s/325d678ksplb7qs/names.json')
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.posts = data;
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // log error
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use a service for this:

```
json.service('getJson', ['$http', function ($http) {
        var promise = null;
        //return service
        return function () {
            if (promise) {
                return promise;
            } else {
                promise = $http.get('url');
                return promise;
            }
        };

    }]);

    function MainCtrl($scope, getJson) {

        getJson().success(function (data) {
            $scope.json = data;

        });

    };
```

Remember to inject the service name in your controller.

Comment: Thanks 
Knostradamus, silly question by  how do I inject the service name in my controller? My html code is currently <section ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

Comment: a few different ways: easiest is to do it directly .controller(controllerName, ['$scope', 'serviceName', function($scope, serviceName) {}]); notice the second part does not have '' around the names

Comment: Thanks, I think I follow you. Do you happened to have a code example of this?